# how to insert multiple rows into the database at the same time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jsp, netbeans

I m doing a mysql database project. In my Webpage there r multiple rows of textboxes,where each row of textboxes correspond to a single entry in the database.

When the user enters data into a single row and press the save button the values r automatically stored in the database but when the user gives two rows(say  two entries for the database) and when he presses the save button the two rows should automatically be inserted into the database.

How can i do this? How shall i read the values from the text boxes and how shall i come to know how much rows the user has entered in the page.

Can anyone help me in doing this?

I m using jsp for insertion and also javascript and ajax.

Comment: What does this have to do with netbeans? What have you done to try and achieve this? We're not here to code for you.

Comment: @Flukey i m using netbeans to create my project.I m just asking for an idea not the code.

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE, it's got nothing to do with a solution to your problem. Unless you're programming a plugin for the IDE itself. So what steps have you done to find a solution?

Comment: @flukey we ask questions here only after trying a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/matheusvmbruno/BLLvZ/

Comment: my page can have n number of rows it is dynamic i may not know how many rows the user is inserting and if the number of rows r more the code will also be big.any solutions like our for loops

Comment: Oh yeah, i noted this after. Edited

Comment: i m not getting u?what did u mean can u please tell me

Comment: can u send me any links for this please.I m not able to understand the code si nce i m new to this one

Comment: i'm creating a example in fiddle. wait a moment

Comment: @matheusvmbruno -  What is this?! why are you creating a SQL string in JavaScript? How does this help him?

Comment: @user1249909 - You should really to start reading up on basic web development.

Comment: @flukey we know the basics i need for multiple insertion thats all if u have any tutorials send me the links

Comment: I thought of producing a sql string in javascript and send to the jsp to handle. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/matheusvmbruno/BLLvZ/

Comment: @matheusvmbruno Thanks a lot. i'll try to use this method.